# WorkManager set up with KOIN

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager, koin

I'm trying to set up work manager to do some work and I'm having trouble initializing it.
Im using KOIN workmaanger dsl

```
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-workmanager:2.2.0-rc-4"
```

and my worker class looks like this

```
class NotificationsScheduler(
    private val dispatchers: AppCoroutineDispatchers,
    private val getTaskUseCase: GetTaskUseCase,
    private val context: Context,
    private val workerParameters: WorkerParameters
) : Worker(context, workerParameters) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
    ...
    }
```

What I've done so far is disabled default initializer

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

My worker module is set up like this

```
val workerModule = module {
    worker { NotificationsScheduler(get(), get(), get(), get()) }
}
```

and it is added in list used in startKoin DSL. I've also used workManagerFactory() DSL to set up factory.

```
startKoin {
        androidContext(this@MyApplication)
        workManagerFactory()
        modules(koinModules)
    }
```

What I'm having trouble with, is that it crashes when app start with exception:

```
 Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class:'androidx.work.WorkerParameters'. Check your definitions!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just take `NotificationsScheduler class` implements KoinComponent and inject the AppCoroutineDispatchers and GetTaskUseCase instances by `inject()` like this:

```
class NotificationsScheduler(context: Context, parameters: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(context, parameters), KoinComponent {
    private val dispatchers: AppCoroutineDispatchers by inject()
    private val getTaskUseCase: GetTaskUseCase by inject()
}
```

In worker module:

```
val workerModule = module {
    worker { OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<AlarmNotificationHandleWorker>().run{
         WorkManager.getInstance(androidContext())
         .enqueueUniqueWork(UUID.randomUUID().toString()
         ,ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND, this)
        } 
    }
}
```

Make sure you had provided the GetTaskUseCase and AppCoroutineDispatchers instances
**Updated**: [Koin](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin) [2.2.0 release](https://doc.insert-koin.io/#/koin-android/workmanager):

```
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-workmanager:2.2.0"
```

Update your Worker class

```
 class NotificationsScheduler(private val dispatchers: AppCoroutineDispatchers,private val getTaskUseCase: GetTaskUseCase,context: Context, parameters: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(context, parameters), KoinComponent {
       
  }
```

And here you are:

```
val workerModule = module {
        worker { NotificationsScheduler(get(),get(),androidContext(),get())  }
    }
```

Thanks [@p72b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5320905/p72b)

Comment: Accepted answer. Removing my params from primary constructor and injecting them by implementing KoinComponent and by inject() does the trick.
Documentation of koin-workmanager is kinda missleading

Comment: Have a look to this post https://medium.com/koin-developers/whats-next-with-koin-2-2-3-0-releases-6c5464ae5e3d

It looks like you are using now with this accepted answer the wrong way and you can remove the org.koin:koin-androidx-workmanager import again.