# inject workmanager through koin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

Hey I am using [Koin](https://insert-koin.io/docs/setup/v3) in my application. I am trying to inject workmanager in my application according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64785386). I did this successfully but I have little bit confused about `workManagerFactory()`

**Module.kt**

```
val workerModule = module {
    // worker definition
    worker { SimpleWorker(get(), get(), get()) }
}
```

**so when startKoin**

```
startKoin {
    androidLogger(Level.ERROR)
    androidContext(appContext)
    modules(
        listOf(
            workerModule
        )
    )
}
```

Do I need to add **wokerModule** in **modules** as well as **workManagerFactory()**?

```
startKoin {
            androidLogger(Level.ERROR)
            androidContext(appContext)
            modules(
                listOf(
                    workerModule
                )
            )
            workManagerFactory()
 }
```

what is the use case `workManagerFactory()`? Can someone please guide me because I am reading this [medium](https://medium.com/koin-developers/whats-next-with-koin-2-2-3-0-releases-6c5464ae5e3d) post. Nothing is mention about it. Thanks